# RMarkdown: knitr::kable::format.args does not work globally

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, kable

I have an R code (RMarkdown) to generate a table with knitr.kable. As I will need to generate several tables with the same formatting, from several data.frames, placed as settings globally. However the format.args option does not work globally.

This way it works:

````
---
title: "Indicadores Fiscais e Gerenciais da Câmara de Vereadores"
author: "Everton da Rosa"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    theme: readable
    number_sections: yes
    df_print: kable
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(
  encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',
  knitr.kable.NA = '',
  knitr.kable.digits = 2,
  knitr.kable.format='latex'
)

knitr_kable_format_args = list(big.mark='.', decimal.mark=',', nsmall=2)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(result = 'hold')


#if (!require("devtools")) install.packages('devtools')
#library(devtools)

if(!require('tidyverse')) install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

if(!require('stargazer')) install.packages('stargazer')
library(stargazer)
```

```{r}
# Caminho para o arquivo com os dados
ds_file <- 'indicadores cm.xlsx'
```

## Resultado Orçamentário

```{r}
df_ro <- readxl::read_excel(ds_file, sheet='ResultadoOrcamentario')
knitr::kable(df_ro, align=c('l', 'r', 'r'), caption='Resultado Orçamentário', format.args = knitr_kable_format_args)
```
````

The Output:

[image: Output]

However, if I remove `format.args` from the `knitr.kable()` call and put it in the `option()` call, it stops working:

````
---
title: "Indicadores Fiscais e Gerenciais da Câmara de Vereadores"
author: "Everton da Rosa"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    theme: readable
    number_sections: yes
    df_print: kable
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(
  encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',
  knitr.kable.NA = '',
  knitr.kable.digits = 2,
  knitr.kable.format='latex',
  knitr.kable.format.args = list(big.mark='.', decimal.mark=',', nsmall=2)
)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(result = 'hold')


#if (!require("devtools")) install.packages('devtools')
#library(devtools)

if(!require('tidyverse')) install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

if(!require('stargazer')) install.packages('stargazer')
library(stargazer)
```

```{r}
# Caminho para o arquivo com os dados
ds_file <- 'indicadores cm.xlsx'
```

## Resultado Orçamentário

```{r}
df_ro <- readxl::read_excel(ds_file, sheet='ResultadoOrcamentario')
knitr::kable(df_ro, align=c('l', 'r', 'r'), caption='Resultado Orçamentário')
```
````

Number formatting no longer works:
[image: The output fails]

I looked for help in the documentation and on the internet, but I didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests putting that value in `options()` should work.  The default for `format.args` is `list()`, not `getOption("knitr.kable.format.args")`.

You might want to make a suggestion to Yihui to make that change.  In the meantime, you can do it yourself:

```
kable <- function(..., format.args = getOption("knitr.kable.format.args", list())
  knitr::kable(..., format.args = format.args)
```

After this, call `kable()` for your version, and `knitr::kable()` for the original one.